# How to call a method with dynamic parameters (can pass or without) C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters

i have a function like this :

```
public void MyMethod(string param1=null, int? param2=null, Datetime? param3=null)
{
     //do something
}
```

So when i call it:

```
MyMethod(param1,null,null) or MyMethod(null,param2,null) ...
```

but i don't like the way above, can i call it as :

```
MyMethod(param1) or MyMethod(param2) or MyMethod(param3)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried? Please show your actual code, tell us in precise detail what happened, and what you wanted to happen instead. Se http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have a method search products with 3 parameters, each times i call it, i have to pass full 3 parameters although it null, but i want to simple code, what way to call it with one or two param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, same type parameters would be a problem in overloading, but i do favor overloading rather than this approach

Call it like this:

```
public void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyMethod(param2: value);
    MyMethod(param1: value);
    MyMethod(param3: value);
}

public void MyMethod(string param1=null, int? param2=null, Datetime? param3=null)
{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: @Nguyễn Huy, try this.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i learn a lot today, but this way vs overloading, which is better?

Comment: Overloading is better because you can control how many of the parameters must be passed in. In @RonaldEstacion example it is possible to call the underlying method directly without passing in any parameters at all - this will not be detected by the compiler as being incorrect.

Comment: @NguyễnHuy because in overloading, just like greg said, you can control the parameters and it's much more cleaner than doing this. Say for instance, you have pre-task to do if you invoke MyMethod wile passing param1, you can control it there. And if you have many parameters, i suggest wrapping it in a class.

Comment: thank you so much for your explain, easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with overloads - i.e. having more than one method called MyMethod.  They will need to have different signatures though, meaning parameters of different types.

So you'd have:

```
public void MyMethod(string param1)
{
     MyMethod(param1, null, null);
}

public void MyMethod(int param2)
{
     MyMethod(null, param2, null)
}
```

You will also need your original method - which the other methods call into.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but in case method have params with same type?i really want to know

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler will throw a syntax error because it's unable to determine which method you are actually calling. You could get around this by giving one method a different name and then calling your base method, but that might not meet your requirements.